# How do you get all uploaded files in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, recursion, file-upload, cakephp-3.0

How do you get all uploaded files in **CakePHP 3.x**? Here is my controller to get you on track.

```php
<?php
class MyController extends AppController {
    public function upload() {
        // how to loop through all files?
    }
}
```

**Sample form**

```html
<form action="/my/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text">
    <!-- any number of file inputs -->
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="file" name="image[]">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <!-- etc. -->
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Comment: Which version of cakephp?

Comment: It's mentioned in the question - 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File upload data isn't stored separately anymore, so if you don't know the names (for whatever reasons), and only have this one blob of data, then you'll have to iterate over it and figure which entry is a file upload array, something like you've shown in your answer.

Personally I've used custom request classes instead in such cases. Here's a simple example where the keys of the processed files data are stored and used for extracting the file uploads afterwards.

```
namespace App\Network;

class Request extends \Cake\Network\Request {

    /**
     * Holds the keys that are being used to store the file uploads
     * in the data array.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $_fileKeys = [];

    /**
     * Returns all file uploads.
     *
     * @return array[]
     */
    public function files() {
        return array_intersect_key($this->data, array_flip($this->_fileKeys));
    }

    protected function _processFiles($post, $files) {
        $filesData = parent::_processFiles([], $files);
        $this->_fileKeys = array_keys($filesData);
        return array_merge($post, $filesData);
    }

}
```

**webroot/index.php**

```
$dispatcher = DispatcherFactory::create();
$dispatcher->dispatch(
    \App\Network\Request::createFromGlobals(),
    new Response()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question. I'm not accepting it yet in case someone comes up with something better or finds a bug.

```js
<?php
class MyController extends AppController {
    public function upload() {
        $files = $this->getFilesArray($this->request->data);
        foreach($files as $file) {
            // move_uploaded_file
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get files recursively in flat array
     *
     * @param mixed $field
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFilesArray($field) {

        if(is_array($field)) {
            if(!empty($field['tmp_name'])) {
                return [$field];
            }
            $files = [];
            foreach($field as $item) {
                $files = array_merge($files, $this->getFilesArray($item));
            }
            return $files;
        }

        return [];
    }

}
```